How to add the visual prompts in chat bot in Azure AI studio
How to add the visual prompts in chat bot in Azure AI studio, we had it in Azure QnA bot.


<img src="https://i.sstatic.net/WBpuFAwX.png" /> 




In Azure OpenAI Service, Click Chat Playground or create a new bot under Bot Management in that you can see the Add Response section there you can include text, images, and cards for custom layouts.

To include visual prompts like buttons in your Azure AI Studio chatbot, you can use Adaptive Cards. Adaptive Cards provide a flexible way to present interactive UI elements, such as buttons, in the bot's responses.
Create Adaptive Cards click on this link Adaptive Cards Designer.

Design the card with buttons or other UI elements.

{
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "What kind of issue are you experiencing with your computer?",
            "wrap": true,
            "weight": "Bolder",
            "size": "Large"
        },
        {
            "type": "Image",
            "url": "https://images.app.goo.gl/5q2Rxb29VF1baDGs9",
            "altText": "Computer Issue",
            "horizontalAlignment": "Center",
            "size": "Medium",
            "spacing": "Small"
        },
        {
            "type": "Input.Toggle",
            "title": "Is this issue urgent?",
            "value": "false",
            "id": "urgentIssue"
        },
        {
            "type": "Input.ChoiceSet",
            "id": "issueType",
            "style": "expanded",
            "label": "Choose the type of issue:",
            "choices": [
                {
                    "title": "Hardware Issue",
                    "value": "hardware"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Software Issue",
                    "value": "software"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Other",
                    "value": "other"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "Input.Text",
            "id": "issueDescription",
            "placeholder": "Briefly describe your issue",
            "isMultiline": true,
            "label": "Issue Description"
        }
    ],
    "actions": [
        {
            "type": "Action.Submit",
            "title": "Submit",
            "data": {
                "action": "submitIssue"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Action.OpenUrl",
            "title": "Get Support",
            "url": "https://example.com/support"
        }
    ],
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "version": "1.3"
}

Once you have the JSON for the Adaptive Card, integrate it into the bot's response in Azure AI Studio.

Test the bot in Azure AI Studio or a supported channel (like Teams or Web Chat) to check the visual prompts are displayed correctly.
